# Wso2 - admin password with encryption

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

Currently if we want to reset admin password of wso2(not through UI), We edit the password in repository/conf/user-mgt.xml file. We would like to use encrypted the password instead of clear text. Is there any way i can give supply my encryption logic to wso2 so that it uses while decrypting the password on authentication. Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can encrypt passwords in configuration files using Cipher Tool shipped with all WSO2 Products. Please refer [1] for more detail on it.

[1] https://docs.wso2.com/display/Carbon420/Securing+Passwords+in+Configuration+Files